# Always align single page site to specific point with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I was wondering if anyone has come across , or has any idea where to start writing, a jQuery script that will always jump to a specific point on a site when you scroll past a certain point. For example take this site http://www.bettondesignwork.co.uk/sierragrande, it is a single page site made up of 4 full size divs that you can navigate to or scroll through, but when you scroll so the bottom of one div and the top of another are both visible, the script will align the most visible div back to the center of the page?

I know this is a little long winded but my jQuery knowledge is rather limited and not sure how i would go about starting this. If anyone has any clues i would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: i dont see what you meant by when both divs are in the same page, it'll align the most visible div. it's not happening to me

Comment: Using FF there is no automatic alignment. Have you view the page's source code and looked at the jQuery in question?

Comment: I think he's asking if a script can be made that will 'align the most visible div'; not that it currently exists on the example page. The script would be easy enough to write; I think the bigger problem is the UX of it. Imagine if you had a high resolution and large monitor where you always see 2 divs. Even if the divs took up the entire screen, if I were to scroll like normal the site would probably jump to the very bottom. But to answer the question; yes it's possible to write it.

Comment: that is what i am hoping to achieve. At present you can scroll to a random point on the screen and it will stay where you scroll too. I am looking to write something for example that when less than half a div is showing the page returns to the previous div, but if you have scrolled down more than 50% the script will pull the next div into view. Any clearer? sorry if not its a tough one to explain!

Comment: This may help you get started: Grab the .position().top of all the major divs, grab the .height() of each div (if different). Add an event listener for on.('scroll') and compare current scrollTop position  to (div + height/2). If true, scrollTop to that div.

Comment: Each div that makes up one page of the site is set to the browser height on load and changes accordingly on every window resize so the user will only ever see 1 div regardless of how big and small their monitor is, its not a vital part of the site i just thought it might be quite a nice feature but having such limited knowledge of jQuery i was hoping someone could poke me towards a starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a beautiful solution for this built into jQM. Because you cant use anchor links in jQM (unless you use data-ajax="false" but thats another problem) jQM developers built internal functionality to simulate this:

```
 $('a.anchor-class').live('click', function(ev) {
     var target = $( $(this).attr('href') ).get(0).offsetTop;
     $.mobile.silentScroll(target);
     return false;
 });
```

More info can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Of course, use top example to create a logic of your own.

You should use scrollstart scrollend events to find your current position, match this to your div collection and scroll to wanted position if needed.